# MySQL function giving same result

Tags: mysql, function

I have created the following function in MySQL and it always give me the result as A whatever the integer number I give as parameter value.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ISICN4A;

CREATE FUNCTION cdn(coden INT) 
RETURNS CHAR
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE coden INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE ret CHAR; 

 SET ret=CASE WHEN coden<=50 then 'A' 
 when coden BETWEEN 51 AND 100 then 'B'     
 when coden BETWEEN 101 AND 350 then 'C' 
 when coden BETWEEN 351 AND 355 then 'D' 
 when coden>355 then 'E'    
 ELSE NULL 
END; 

RETURN ret; 
END;$$

DELIMITER $$
```

Appreciate your kind review and suggestion to modify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function accepts a parameter `coden INT`, but in function body you declare a variable with the same name as your parameter. 
Try to remove `DECLARE coden INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;` from your function body
so that your function will look like:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ISICN4A;

CREATE FUNCTION cdn(coden INT) RETURNS CHAR
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE ret CHAR; 

    SET ret=CASE WHEN coden<=50 THEN 'A' 
    WHEN coden BETWEEN 51 AND 100 THEN 'B'     
    WHEN coden BETWEEN 101 AND 350 THEN 'C' 
    WHEN coden BETWEEN 351 AND 355 THEN 'D' 
    WHEN coden>355 THEN 'E'    
    ELSE NULL 
END; 

RETURN ret; 
END;$$
```